# How to print concatenation of some operations in TCL

Tags: variables, printing, tcl, concatenation

Say there is a code like this:

```
set val "Hello"
set listA {}

lappend listA 6 7
```

Now I want to puts the following:

```
puts "${val} user! Your list contains two values. First is [lindex $listA 0] and the second is [lindex $listA 1]"
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the answer. The problem was in the fact that in my actual code I was using "[" and "]" symbols as a string but without "\".

So I need to write:

```
puts "Zone No ${key} has Range\[ [lindex $value 0] - [lindex $value 1] \]"
```

Sorry for the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fully sure if I understood correctly. But what you did should work, with a small modification:

```
set val "Hello"
set listA {6 7}
# or:
# set listA {}
# lappend listA 6 7
puts "${val} user! Your list contains two values. First is [lindex $listA 0] and the second is [lindex $listA 1]"
```

Gives the output:

```
Hello user! Your list contains two values. First is 6 and the second is 7
```